# Consulta sobre dígitos de un producto javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas desde ayer a la noche ando dando vueltas con un ejercicio de javascript, con el mismo pude practicar varias cosas que no había aplicado hasta ahora como el parámetros Rest o tener que pasar los números a strings para poder manejarlos de una forma mas sencilla.
El ejercicio pide lo siguiente para ser resuelto:

```
sumDigProd(16, 28) ➞ 6
// 16 + 28 = 44
// 4 * 4 =  16
// 1 * 6 = 6

sumDigProd(0) ➞ 0

sumDigProd(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ➞ 2
```

Es decir que pasa un numero indefinido de números los cuales tienes que sumar y en base a esa suma multiplicarlos y separarlos hasta que quede solo un digito.
Lo que yo llegue a armar hasta ahora es lo siguiente, se que no es mucho pero empece hace poco con javascript:

```
function prueba (...values) {
  var suma = values.reduce((previus,current) => { return previus + current;});
  if (suma > 10) {
     suma =suma.toString().split('').join(" * ");
     suma = eval(suma);
    return suma;
  }
  else { 
    return  suma;
  }
}
console.log(prueba(4, 4, 5, 6, 7)) => 12
```

Todavía no me manejo muy bien con las funciones flecha o los distintos operadores que se pueden usar como los ? y demás, por eso consulto si voy por buen camino o que otras opciones podría aplicar.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Venis bien pero faltaria un bucle en caso que la suma vuelva a dar `>10` en la multiplicacion de sus digitos y se tenga que repetir la condicion , podes evitar `eval()` y `join()`  , ya que si volves a utilizar reduce esta vez podes multiplicar todos los digitos previamente separados en un array como bien lo hiciste con `toString().split('')`

- la condicion es simple , te la dejo con while , evaluando que resultado sea > 10 para que se siga repitiendo el ciclo
- un pequeño tip a saber es que podes ahorrar el `return` y las `{}` en las funciones de flecha si tenes una expresión simple

```js
function prueba (...values) {

  
  var resultado = values.reduce((previus,current) =>  previus + current);
  
  while(resultado>10){
  
  resultado= resultado.toString().split('').reduce((acc,num)=>acc*num)
    
  }
  
  return resultado
   
}
console.log(prueba(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, lo aplicare y seguire practicando